# OnClickListener Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

my item_layout xml (see it like a template) contain a cardview with some texts and one button, when I run the application. the recyclerview shows two card views with different text (actor names, actors movies) all its ok, but the problem is when I made the button with an onclicklister method to show other activities. the result is when I click on button of the first card view and the button of the second cardview it shows the same result. 
what I want is when I click on button on the first cardview it shows Activity number 2, and when I click on the button on the second cardview must shows Activity number 3.

ps: I want different result when I click on button of each cardview

xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">


    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#7f89e9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtCelebMovie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="heur/travaille : 5:00 pm - 8:00 am." />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="emplacement de travaille : cité12  - cité42. "
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="statut : disponible."
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="............"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="...................................."
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go"
        android:id="@+id/buttonfordialog"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            };






        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.MyToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Alert ! ");


        ArrayList<Celebrity> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        fillDummyData(itemList);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, btnListener);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }

    private void fillDummyData(ArrayList<Celebrity> celebList) {
        Celebrity celeb1 = new Celebrity();
        celeb1.setName("Johny.D");
        celeb1.setFamousMovie("Pirates  ");
        celeb1.setProfilePhotoLocation("@drawable/contact1");
        celebList.add(celeb1);

        Celebrity celeb2 = new Celebrity();
        celeb2.setName("Arnold");
        celeb2.setFamousMovie("The Terminator");
        celeb2.setProfilePhotoLocation("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3MDc4NzUyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTQyMTc5MQ@@._V1._SY209_CR13,0,140,209_.jpg");
        celebList.add(celeb2);
    }
}
```

the Adapter :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

private List<Celebrity> celebrityList;
private final View.OnClickListener btnListener;

public ItemAdapter(List<Celebrity> celebrityList, View.OnClickListener btnListener) {
    this.celebrityList = celebrityList;
    this.btnListener = btnListener;
}

@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

    return new ItemHolder(itemView, btnListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Celebrity item = celebrityList.get(position);
    holder.txtCelebName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.txtCelebMovie.setText(item.getFamousMovie());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return celebrityList.size();
}

    public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private  Button buttoncalling;
        public TextView txtCelebName, txtCelebMovie;
        public ImageView profileImage;

        public ItemHolder(View view, View.OnClickListener btnListener) {
        super(view);
            txtCelebName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCelebName);
            txtCelebMovie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCelebMovie);
            profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            buttoncalling  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfordialog);
            buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 2):

define OnClickListener       inside          onBindViewHolder();

```
      String [] activities={"FirstActivity","SecondActivity","ThirdActivity"};
      String packageNamePrefix="com.example."
    //String packageNamePrefix="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"


          @Override
          public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder,final int position) {
          Celebrity item = celebrityList.get(position);
          holder.txtCelebName.setText(item.getName());
          holder.txtCelebMovie.setText(item.getFamousMovie());

        holder.buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new 
                    Intent(MainActivity.this,Class.forName(packageNamePrefix+activities[position]));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
       });
      }
```

it will launch FirstActivity,SecondActivity,ThirdActivity respectively.
I hope it will help.

Comment: with what i must replace "com.example"  in       String packageNamePrefix="com.example."

Comment: It is your package name you can find that on your AndroidManifest.xml with name of package="somthing.something.something". replace "com.package" with that.

Comment: thanks , i found it ,  I want each button of cardview Open different Activity. give me a solution, please I need it. for example  button of cardview number 2  open Activity 2 , and button of cardview number3 open Activity 3 .

Comment: Read this question and the answers you can find a solution. You just need to implement on click listener to the button in cardview inside your  RecyclerviewAdapter. You can follow the given answers to get your thing done.

Comment: but the onclick listener to the button in cardview inside my Recyclerviewadapter give the same result (All buttons of All card views open the same Activity). like I said in the question I need different result .

Comment: where you are implementing button's on click method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123813/discussion-between-c89-hd-and-ajith-pandian).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement `OnClickListener` inside `RecyclerView` adapter.

1. You can implement click listener inside `onBindViewHolder()` method like below

   ```
   holder.buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      // perform click operation
   });
   ```
2. You can also implement it inside you `ItemHolder` like this

   ```
   buttoncalling.setOnClickListener( new  View.OnClickListener(){
      // perform click operation    
   });
   ```

and use `getAdapterPosition()` whenever you need item clicked position as recommended in [official docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

3. You can also make **interface callbacks** to your Activity and pass position along with it for refrence.

Comment: how can i use getAdapterposition  ? give me an example .

Comment: when you want position in **ItemHolder** to get which position was clicked to get data from **List<Model>** then you need **getAdapterPosition()** method

Comment: i dont know how to use it ?

Comment: here is a nice tutorial [Android Working with Recycler View](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) hope it helps. If it help you upto some extent please accept it as answer and upvote . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline onclickListener like below;

```
YOURBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       // your codes goes here...
   }
});
```